# Can someone please explain the following code from OSTEP, I wonder how the execvp creates and program and how it works

Tags: c, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc<0){
        
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
        
    }else if (rc == 0){
        printf("hello, I am child(pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
        char *myargs[3];
        myargs[0] = strdup("wc");
        myargs[1] = strdup("p3.c");
        myargs[2] = NULL;
        execvp(myargs[0],myargs);
        printf("this shouldn't print out");
    
    }else{
        int rc_wait = wait(NULL); 
        printf("hello, I am parent of %d (rc_wait:%d) (pid:%d)\n", rc, rc_wait, (int) getpid());
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

from line 15 to line 19, it creates a new program or process, "wc", to count how many lines, words and bytes are found in the current file p3, I read this code multiple times and have no idea how it works, as what I know currently the function "strdup" returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of its parameter s, the syscall "execvp" replaces the current process with the new process.

output

```
prompt> ./p3
hello world (pid:29383)
hello, I am child (pid:29384)
29 107 1030 p3.c
hello, I am parent of 29384 (rc_wait:29384) (pid:29383)
prompt>
```

My question:

1. How can the strdup creates a new program "wc"?
2. How the "wc" automatically becomes a word counter program? Is this some kind of build-in method?
3. How the execvp executes the new process "wc"? when it replaces the current process, where it starts again in it's child process?

I understand it now, if you are looking for the same question, see the comment below

thanks again!

Comment: 1) `strdup` creates a new string and not a process. 2) `wc` *is* a word counter program 3) It does not execute a new process, it is replacing the current one (which happens to be a child of the main process which was `fork`ed).

Comment: @EugeneSh. why the "WC" is a program, how it be generated?

Comment: It is a standard Linux command line utility [`man wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ohh! I think I understand it now, so initially, the parent process fork a child process, as the wait() function, the child process is running first, and then within the child process, the execvp is triggered so the child process gets replace, and print something else, finally, when it is done, it backs to parent process..

Comment: Those `strdup()`s are pointless, btw. `myargs[0] = "wc";` etc. works just as well. No need to make a copy first. (Might need to adjust the type of `myargs` though)

Comment: The last line of output is coming from the *parent* process after the child process exits.

Comment: @Shawn I think I understand it now, so initially, the parent process fork a child process, as the wait() function, the child process is running first, and then within the child process, the execvp is triggered so the child process gets replace, and print something else, finally, when it is done, it backs to parent process

Comment: Basically, yes.